# Who stole the bitcoins?

Tags: knowledge, computer-puzzle, imgur-maze

#### Introduction

You want to give bitcoins to a person you have met. Part of the deal is to give the bitcoins in the *most* untraceable way. So you have decided to send an email to him with the address (you already have sent the private key). The email you sent to him is shown here below:

**Email 1:**

> I have already sent the private key to you in another email.
>
> To get the bitcoin address, please take a look at the attachments,
>
> Regards,
>
> *****

The attachment lead to this image:

> ### [image]

**Email 2:**

It looked as if everything went smooth, until you got an email back from the person you sent the email to. The email he sent is shown below:

> Hi,
>
> It seems that the wallet you sent me is empty,
>
> Regards,
>
> *****

---

#### The task

It seems that the bitcoin wallet was already emptied by someone else. Your task is to find out who has *stolen* the bitcoins.

---

#### Tips

Tip 1:

> It was not the person you have sent the email to.

Tip 2 (**important**}:

> The name of the person who stole the bitcoin is in [this](http://pastebin.com/4K5vkhRb) list.

Comment: Is the `>` by the QR code intentional?

Comment: Well, decrypting that QR code gives me 'NGnc7', which is probably the extent of my usefulness.

Comment: As a side question, how did you generate the names?

Comment: When I scanned the QR code and googled it, the first result was this puzzle with part of the solution shown in the preview. How ironic.

Comment: @fabriced I generated the names with [this website](http://listofrandomnames.com/index.cfm?textarea) (done multiple times to get 250 names). After that, I made an 05AB1E script (which can be found [here](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=fHYxPzMzRsW-Sy5SP30iIC0gIj95LA&input=TmFtZSAxCk5hbWUgMgpOYW1lIDMKRXRjLg)) to generate the addresses.

Comment: *Who stole the Bitcoins from the Bitcoin wallet?* **Adnan stole the Bitcoins from the Bitcoin wallet!** *Who me?* **Yes you!** *Wasn't me...* **Then who?!**

Comment: @corsiKa ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hmm. Cannot the address be derived from the private key already?

Comment: @Thilo It seems that that is actually possible. I didn't know that until now :p.

Comment: @Adnan Your pastebin says "Note that _none_ of the above addresses or names _do not_ represent real bitcoin addresses or names of people." - That's a double negative, can lead to confusion

Comment: The QR code step doesn't seem to be accurate anymore. I'm not sure how else to say this without spoiling anything..

Comment: @MrDuk How is not accurate? I tested it with my QR scanner and got the right code.

Comment: @Adnan the url doesn't work anymore

Comment: @MrDuk It's a Stack Imgur address, not a regular Imgur address. The regular seems to expire after some time...

Comment: Sending bitcoin by transferring the wallet is not secure, the sender can sweep it before the receiver or send the same wallet to multiple people, unconfirmed transactions can also be reversed or double-spent, always use the block chain and wait for at least 6 confirmations.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solution:

> Bee Holzman

Explanation:

When the QR code is decrypted, we are given `NGnc7`. As @LeppyR64 figured out, this is an Imgur address, which leads us to this image:

> [image: Bitcoin logo]

Open this image with a text editor and you will find the bitcoin address at the end (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Jtl.png) for an image):

> `1GJ2CBCjBjqa7F9XscorRTfoUXAA2G4FHV`.

Running a blockchain search for this address gives us :

> One transaction: -0.02 BTC to the address `14j3zgcJoDGPzfUNEUzMAPHB57E4xVBSoL`.

And that address belongs to...

> Bee Holzman.

<sub>Most of this is from @LeppyR64's [partial answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33601/21703), I just finished off.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer to include all the information after getting the check.  Good work!

Comment: lol I got this one on imgur http://imgur.com/a/ngNC7

Answer (score 33):

Partial - No time to finish it now

As was mentioned by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33599/1777) the QR-Code decodes to:

> NGnc7 - This is an imgur address

This points to a new image:

> [image]

With this image:

> Edit it with notepad and you'll find at the end of file the text
> "The address is 1GJ2CBCjBjqa7F9XscorRTfoUXAA2G4FHV"

Next Step:

> This is a bitcoin address of the empty wallet.  So now I don't know how to find the transactions and don't have time to research it now.  Hopefully someone can continue or I will come back later.

Answer (score 8):

Using a QR Scanner, I get the text

> NGnc7

I imagine that in the list of suspects the line of letters and numbers will have the first two capitals N and G, the two lowercase letters after that n and c and the first number after that 7

Alternatively it could be something to do with the initials

**EDIT**: The others realized it was an imgur adress, which lead to Bee Holzman. Guess I was wrong

Comment: NGnc7 is correct.  Your suspicion is wrong.  (I'm already on the next step) ;)

Comment: @LeppyR64, well done you, I have no idea what to do now!

Comment: No initials either haha :p

Comment: I can find `nc7` in one of the addresses...

Comment: @GeorgeGibson Check my answer.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Solved!

Answer (score 8):

Continuing on @LeppyR64's answer:

> When we check the transactions on the bitcoin wallet with the address we obtained, we see a transaction to address: 14j3zgcJoDGPzfUNEUzMAPHB57E4xVBSoL

Which belongs to:

> Bee Holzman