# Stealing the bitcoins back

Tags: knowledge, computer-puzzle

#### Introduction

In the [**last challenge**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33597/who-stole-the-bitcoins), you found out who stole the bitcoins. Now is the task to steal the bitcoins back. I didn't manage to steal them back so I'm going to give you the hints that I found. **Let's get started**.

---

#### Story

First of all, I hacked into Bee Holzman's laptop and found the following files:

> **Zinc.txt**

Which contained the following text:

> [**recursion**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41635/stealing-the-bitcoins-back)

The second file is:

> [**Molybdenum.txt**](http://pastebin.com/3nZ6gM6Z) (pastebin link) (text also found below)

It contains 150 private keys for bitcoin addresses, but I checked all of them and they we're all empty. I didn't understand why though.

The last thing I found was a script. A *very weird script* that can be found [here](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MTY3NjQzMTI3ODU2NDRJMjE0w7Y3ODk1JTQrRkQqwqcxMDDCo33CrCJISktISktISktISktIInPDqDVzwqs_NjJCNDnCoyJJMGxPIiJKMUxQIuKAoSw&input=VGVzdA). It seems to decrypt a password filled in in **input** and converts it to a private key.

---

**Do you know what the private key is?**

---

To prevent link rot, the external data linked to above can also be found below.

Pastebin Contents:

```
Molybdenum.txt

5HEUvjdY7r76UXrS19gBL8eJU2mKWn1UndF6p4RB8gYRubyFERB
5JJURS6ggDeQEVnorCWrswvJEw26DSaominKLzdeksWqQJkDymH
5JURoSTwtRUwTMFVtZZZyEY7XQeNgh49RDaxFDAFbMaNYngtmu3
5JfJYawNAncbi9UbscyzktURZhxWz1Q9ygZWkfG7yZLuXgLJpJ8
5KeNNexg5yq8NVFo6MZTwm3jmB9PVBU2zANy98KitxNPLH4fX95
5HhzHWxugpCM2VzxH6Bq9Yz6gRNMo5Z16Um8xmX8N4t7ryjS3wH
5K9LGhWxpD8fsegiYNQqFvRiEPcGgogvGPiggTCDVZuSUH6THuP
5KxFppuVkFYoVzcRBJCW6ihbRT52T9Ahtc4YCPyLSZvp714hnVa
5JL7vEwo6fNZzfPYxKYn2uuJSM5ttvvwBxYmQ4zFWiBMHUFGvCw
5JRHrAoB8xwW2UTsV3d38c9ngNZvZPJCeMKJMgRSRX6XVwk982m
5JRHTVibNdMMh9a9yyDqkJU1jmTehvj6mv7WuwYrsFeQ7dVpQCf
5HP2nRxugCKRv72vCSRhviuCPeHk1GkD58HpxwYWV7WnaenWG7h
5HqphpUVWyYF7Svq85hhThjDyxEPN92toUgb7UmFV6n9peQcw3Q
5JdFd1DD8FYCK7gq2xCSr7YNB9wYDwnCwyk8xZFGTeVGqndQFnx
5J1UfcKm4dBteSVAL8vdBaqi8pfrzGf8pzvZcFDxjwuNkkPjtPi
5JfKe1LBS8kjdm7kTwLsWgGb3Ur464ibkb9NLAzxP8qXuHJHZ14
5JkEr1Yx9BEVFF5zodAKyMuxBcWBAyCxehonjt1nUXu3hsGjwFp
5K9DjZn4zamtKyhYC4WYbpbwbf2kAJ4KVd3t5FtMXrTUHRBUFfN
5J2mxu56V6yYsj5Mbe6A5DeCaNHgp4bdc75pLPPRamQCDgo3256
5KY6DE5SKjGtQTbjz4nTDV19F6NPG7aP3pbaCbVnRmhrUiMeg9Z
5HC53xdgB8S6WeiHWuAegfyGwG6Y78fWgUjx64fUJ1abQuXxWD9
5K8cEnjQPy8io5BywYQo1FRCX77YTF3EFa4Uuj6JrXvnTjUzoCn
5JrQ73Rd4QD9fwgWsJWxsQdks8qApGqSQNu6mn1zHdYQ5UxqeoK
5JLFxTozpQCgvT6a6dAYYfHXdgi4azskHfUf7nWF6qX7P31Qm7d
5KALHRBdqq8KfboyNVeYRGKx7brekJBvpAMouKaTzoPJ1RnPUFK
5H2njzQ8vA4bKZx8QcA9KVceBBh7XAZyXkpzs5ca4QVmKyp5RFi
5JbybCuV1GxvoaFZJ1tcGx4boruguaoFNrS2TcZEnNaZ7Xa66yK
5KGYSW683q5RomaXRZUbuiXG8oe6auqKxbhQHffqV2DYWfUZdTd
5K7FkeHrZ89ojsg8YA9Q1DSSQrLcPn3pLdkkCLuA2WdzEpgD4ro
5JAVrEjmw7vXqEJxWz1HUeZpo3zRgsA3UjmxP3tJihh8uuTZZxq
5HMMR4hEGAZKGaseoyyxrKkrUKQZx5ktj3LRYYnx7B8q6F3tmyw
5H3Z5r4vT8kMsMv9xYQWRDxSLppEtBkx9iy3udMnoBZ1kTpKZAz
5Jmcbqz6UuezsmgZiTQjvZNpTkX4UaKn97tCVXU1Xy1rRYbr2q4
5K1YdcbVYFcf3wbzHMWRipcia87iSEDQ2PGTDXGSGMPipUybCuf
5HpALTeFFwAHSFRhxJUwU8z72FBCgJStPVx8C6rWKRVp5Qn3Mrw
5HfYr9sFmiTyy8bAkTQBAMtGfNhsXvcGnUfKwb1UHAXK8zXZPds
5KcnUxgjGrZrbdFdSZcnzXMYH9oLg6qzREKZt99DX3MbLH6pXjh
5H7Ubn1LG6oUfDGs6obDnRTsXzB7gJPh5iaKnx1dYgfxBwtE8Bq
5KUCFXxqJv5bHfyogPkDyKBebzZAKqxomb9fmwDuCPhBoAzf8Xa
5HFwcyxLQcTvBfusdALvzYseQv9Gr5fzuMiHgid8K73gKQijJyA
5JEUGk5nDUKALJAVTwhRHXo5JqAgJbgCzDcGqH6At9ssXP3TDqr
5Kcdmh7f9j49v3PHizmoZeMb4c4WyE5o1deS8J9RkZsYDG3kEYd
5JYYimawEAej1qQ1MKr85gmiHguMKR4ah4A7Tiz2YT6YVTFFZ4f
5Jq9rGnEqHGr5RskpewgSZxxJ9sZD5Fz78bV3NmKBJuRKQzihqb
5JFwNeYJTJvfJkEYPmD3Yzvbq5hjhpx7EA8YtSTDhYoWJxvmH1j
5Jmv9yNGj6FN5FpepoNeXDbpV4JkufqiMR7B5XfYXpzPGFrHLSV
5JNdF76BhxKx3Tn9EfuQZGjbSVUxSNowkX4BF1zpU5wZD1X8Jas
5JHZskzhP6pYtghkqsn9e1qkKpvMDjDpyxkZpcHAfbJrnUQLMmN
5KNaeNJTaiku2GAJBiyGY4w64XKXdpAQF5qWktfwoV5fjX24EVU
5KD91ejf73tezuDeBzE1PgvP2t6CCe8u7FFa6tVhEh1P8ntVARe
5HVjK2H2VeTyYmtgdibhMrUJT77yx7Z1euC9KYEjXBGkdjekMsN
5H3k9faP1uFkbMPK3ajNHKHEgtgtvS74fVhB6FTu1sfcBLdtcnw
5JdyzfU9nrHzUwf7bHAodvf3dtft1f8c8bMJpztRPpJHhKWzXKd
5HCXWpDgUSGFA5NkC923sYGtAHb1hth2baZACgsyzMA4qHsBfQD
5KYwKJ81j3jSGHGKUvsHqCi2Zy6tyhwXj7ZUnt81dG76m4XWH2H
5JaMrBXBDtEjvxEDdTNCfWiy1Wgcc84qwLE6V2yM6TSMTZrzoCb
5H3JruoQhA1MLr61SbTRHodZnjHvY6gbVZJZbcVShifnsENFw57
5JM7qDFnQC5hKMpkXahixn5F5fFrS7LQVREDBVXHkz5C6kw5CSQ
5JXV2XF7KYK6TeJaDuej72t4hwUxMVaeM6m3QqrCABWJ6eQ7RMX
5JqnTZMUgVHgDm2YruPHcjUPA8uZnJ5ocaZF4AVcKqHVz8CjBRw
5KhrsoRpsHhcBcfJRGiDsdHz18rQ1M3xCx6nhFUmXakMNiR3fQR
5JFsqmJKbwG8GsVEgRdmmURKnDQ7Kuws18odGoEqDvbFQzV9Ew6
5KowouSwRL1g1wf9tpSMbMzyFEeaFu5CzNNvKjtDAixAnQ9GRPP
5Hih6H9hyWXYn1EnA1TQwJ1nKbBn2wwsHtCRzc6yjSECCLAQPRr
5KK679qdt9cDwUmP4gsYXS1K56Hi6RpHJmom2ra2pWhkgfZnPtF
5Kt5QQmZhx8Cbcv1HseLmiqShnXny2JGdfAqwcNV4ihVKAkyEyC
5KCD2qXzbhvTmsWVUvd47DrTsG19oU3oK8wvkmUWZZvmSR97ea3
5HRK5gviPMuxYpWog6hbi3Y25pYjKj4gMPJPaFNk8EzLn9iz4YX
5KqYayGRhBQZAagEmAvEiYYWggHfmJY9FtCPcVNFoF5ZmmH6MhA
5KD2H9mbQk9gUBKTroCe5tCt4YCHDFNRpZsQaLdAxgrXnr7AZBg
5KW9ECSfzuV3TC3wFwKdrHwiBALufmFyLLtyj4JacRkDf9Rw8ok
5KRafZKMn7jfU6UoYumNtx5HQNpGcgsgXKLSYJAd9444Ro8ZJkd
5KR1zjayL5c2PYhf3w8nEEFCf1cV1kRW3D4PnKNhab3MDMzCww6
5JTZuR4icDfDspAeKp762jTE3CwryxS6XJtrFohm2QZMHsWvsdJ
5HPWBNCixBAoeLbKyEpnHp7dSCrvWrnKBLBij24pSHJ8yVgcvSU
5KFbCmJgtpQ9nyjEFiaeT9cKJCSTYD6FftbQ93ngchNfmCo4Bc8
5HKQSGkfK2kAHTLor1JoRJtPypJjHK49VxGcxEuCLyvwaeHmbQt
5HfXpzbCDvaPdsHUgRXwCrjcNbg5EQSupR4o6fvxWFu8REwyBNQ
5HLok7BsWWtMShaJmBctapFrKP8jX5XCcVsX4zdrX857aaKb9dc
5JaZjxT2AhBc7bG9bYc7pGFxDbXF2BpjEGRa62veuojELhKBnP3
5KBFFyWpw3BiHMXDFZxdPtjCxsWcPH3WN5nNArb2K6FauRvqveb
5Kn74kmtbvBcHLzCjFMkF93c7WTyKeS6XuhiDpLzRgupRHTPxtF
5J67Jm7ygwJ5Q5kKNdgoHQC25oLKStY6Fp6uqtkjhu4XW2sriJy
5JmLb9jj2W6wsuh5kvsUinHDdeTrkA39K2cfs5iC5ysenv5c72x
5Hev855ZJetRKmD4XPtSNFLFs8aEHR1kyTzQyLjdafWozrcTo3S
5HYNVj8iWWER7gTjmteebCzH6QDAnvna6Xf3txF5qg9JjhJvWMD
5KvTKeiGWkhuaaGtVCrsKWMh6R8Hs9dmjCL8NG5Ax52DLWuE9mM
5JK7yJu9fgB5adxmwBGZLgXWfZx9GgmwnW3ihdXn7mkyiFLqNsj
5HATEiHBPSeQv5j2EkHRqaws27gy28dX8KVDuyRzgJztXjKfggU
5KDQKMjE1PZYWuJTuMWQFzzw83H5qYaJeqUtLfBaG7dXPZrLxMG
5KgUMo84LxWs6v3sf7CvtF6fkvJT6shmjtjQv8Jui2z4Tvakb6F
5K87MyBncH1RMYBxiiM5w3uy9h4hvKXmwYLpWcjthYyFqiotNBo
5JpzUtfCprEXz5NrpuCydgPRi8UT8sf2QDpPb75cDaLwXuui2J7
5JAAQmVapXvMY4Nrea78nxYHNMqhgA2NFMjKVn39nWDr77jCKiE
5JvxkU4KaaTeNLjBMKUnEUrzs9348zxbpY54Yk7QgpQ6vKh5WVM
5KGPyRmYz8JkDXTMp9t1cZiUVg4bmB5z9KKqJYEcwmHMArneCYP
5HBQmTdLVmiCmvhziqZhQURbRVQZ8NiEFfzaQ42r3oU7zBFBVpe
5JFLCY66gMMMod7ANcsX8SdxDxcgQMKg5XKfACxsHETCo1Vu7Yt
5H6EhWTyEqt22zok1PCDR6nqhduQahzZKxkZ1pQthuAXmHBgPJT
5HMFEkQW9MEaFJuDxDYB3A8MGVRsSiRzXsD7RAEywxrycBj6M4E
5Jak3359oLAG2us7ytWBHLeFDknz3qGLnaxoaWqPkYxj3wSW9KZ
5HQonFUhwByxwEHqzgwSqPaEvtHAEM8yspeC5r4xzK7kzsgVtNi
5JqKyTKoi6FsGprjpWgTntVimCP53JDYrUfJZv59NHUUvbhZAR1
5HGfRebSpfFwadmwR1hD9ZVw8P13nLzRqAUsoU6MSw5Jkp7tyVE
5HdNMVFYJHsBGUn2m5SqXVeHK4vzMujNW153XimkY394q7GPBJH
5HnxCfZg1F99ztjZbfgoAd3cuXbQBdSXdCdvc7eUpMy7H5tHdZh
5H1uFriM3dwo4XewZs9nAx5g59YDvBQeK8cbrPtCy7DRG8982Be
5JNRpEyzmCDo52pgMzQPnG2pkiC5AB8gSxVwQg3WZDrpFN51ik4
5JVn4HSu3dbrhWHmKba1Y6v7KQPw8ApbNmc77FYgBxG9k5xvogJ
5KPdQMCwnntekmXGJGymeUF9EUoCrbsSC93vMgR3Z4YLoQwaxts
5K6paJ5hdmF26Z6CRJorUFdcMsPjSYsqpxxW56pPGboPtV3xqcS
5HdndYJQZ4Ah9hQFuqZL9PzrHuoUknk1rniQNywewkNnuRny8Ew
5Jcm6BTjEjfsyNhBaUAYku477jnzWEtSDUDp4jbGxB43VDBBY7h
5HCtWa495XdQUvWuqjRswX4ggt4RCZpbdjhrmGLFGsq9SfvaTz8
5Kugaji6xHEpb5VwU5GLKBat9JNBthTJ8AJ9ygPDYU8LpXwmjKR
5JJu2PMBhNAKGWeXG8AG3wDwKW1Ngs1qAEUEp9BdMgjZh1a6y3q
5HvtTpAS4k3VkPhCp2mULxEGENmAwTysP8D6BS6ppbTaJkK4oL2
5KsJ2TKJggzavq9ErLzoidQo1YgLQkXmSQfvv3eLWw8zfUHVvbx
5HEqqinkUGerCLKxKEM2ytxy7YfPxECtEFhD1Pr7x6ppsCxxeC3
5KkaE9yeNWE9vohFQ6i5strwj4nmmM7UEsLMnsDkXSSrstR3FWs
5K7F9YgcupdNKvSyeikLfMQxMAJaBQWtX7ri7Pjdop1gqgdKS8U
5HUrTvpsKeXna2YYxHpSCVJ7SucJXXdrDjydvFHDZtvVXkFX7Sk
5HWak6CYgyNuuxxwi2EAoP7VRww5Ki99rMyYwbsypC3R5ZAqvTj
5KhUrHgocJFpXfpTuNhvEvZvBkGDaqx66ApmHZzbzNBTpFfZmWP
5H2D2JXoiX4jUJreVMTv2dSeTvKW5ntjFNtAo5ufEvafNwYe67y
5H2uBm2ijzTYawA8up9bUwVvrvhLnHTeyLazF5THQ8P2EcQtMd7
5KB4Hx1r1nZAh3CGP5MoYP79MiefyKfQCpdKboTPnqYvBaedRM3
5JMWwsLZnVZWCEYbsftjuC7PU6KjP7csVACNwYWLrM2nrUQxs7J
5JaVUvCwsHNXcwYG7UEHkdJhZdh2jzAaXSNgQa1UKBGU4BXsysw
5HCWsT6dVE6MuGimYgqggrqyyEo3jpCPtQy6dwQtaGDMGiwGZmJ
5K5hWUM8sfV2hW3zoXXSt8raCHRPHgLiSiqQJQJPgqHjVjvAf8D
5HkVXzf1gcH6k4CYtf6NVxxxnvpbXx1T1GQCNjV8QZxDQXfcbQY
5KxLVvpyEttmd2K5QnecgNAsJyFGqnBdGCBuocmusJjfQCYeJUB
5H5FKC1rB57hZv7SJ6jrjEfFQ7GfTtMCgmmH1F4RckJLzWMAyDv
5JLKpfBHo2BmnhLB2C2zDyhuXt8kBgFkqRtSYPGjthG26eGbdaj
5HyGkjgBxRTGVCXmJNrVviPrzJagodM1tHpKQEmf1n5JwkGRkW8
5KAAit5qHczzaqKVo88KvppumQHnFt9fXfm3usouCFFEqtnLZ9W
5JLA3xkNioSFyFhWhWq6kJKznc5SiL7GDRDanNsriwNM6HboGqz
5KZA9fJPrL9WGx7sCcq41mNvSZBpS6zPV3mzWnnRbyBXHtLFb6p
5JGewR3idBbBKijdXN4KrBKhcuVEyDahvodcJNVDFLi1sycnM86
5KWSb7ui3k5fKJnET2pdrYXAWHckYiH9r4GRVZ8a7HYkM8EXm11
5KQwcuTWmzJBmZscrsQxWQ6UZ5RNZ35hNGmaNfviVVEsZFtpHCF
5KeATp4pJz1u89z2Xn5naCDwHUXGsi3CL5qZqjFbaD3NEjMCnVL
5JMKPZedfmVZtBDMfQxdtzqkrm8wvrCnteELouoPsSMgUgHqB3u
5JXTWQMNHxYxpyLeXwLqHjNVg85nDrREq6FvVDyrUCud5zATKYS
5HDpr2SsUNURoXutbYCHG71YkCsoyJu7spRigSYb7fj692JDBem
5HDuZmTobPaVjuZRH58fDBGJwYHwmAasxR7qa3at9YvsJzBWdQ8
5HJwQkBCxqn2TyWeC6L7H6quk4Pztez9Fjk4ZD7ypK8JhNSeQaa
5JUkZ8hJux2f7PqtNZj5kPhoYQQxULctrXnDcYYjb5BRpF4jhg1
5HenY8dwYAJYjVJCEofjrpX4R4FAMDKcKT31S91f3GtCq5MGdqZ
```

Very Weird Script:

```
16764312785644I214ö7895%4+FD*§100£}¬"HJKHJKHJKHJKH"sè5s«?62B49£"I0lO""J1LP"‡,
```

... written in [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), a golfing language that is, as of the time of this writing, the first language listed at http://tryitonline.net/ due to alphabetic sorting on that site

---

#### Hints

> **Hint 1:** the SHA256 hash of the key is `d60f9c637d9d5a067fdb33751ce56a97760b5bef208b3688f2a663b7903675f1`.

> **Hint 2:** the keys in the file **Molybdenum.txt** have no bitcoins in it, and have therefore no meaning (*do they?*).

Comment: Once we have a candidate key how do we check if it could be correct? Is there some way to check ourselves?

Comment: @AvikMohan I have added a SHA256 version of the key.

Answer (score 1):

#### Step 1: Figuring out the password

I have used 4 potential passwords:

> Zinc, recursion, Molybdenum and Test (Unlikely)

These give respectfully:

> 5HNivwnPCJ4bmwJ2RfPfdZQdMsqLsLxsvF7xj1HWAgsP9SPEsJk, 5J2sEtNF8ePJLvLgHPMUKuAR32PJRsAf2EB7d5MjNnkvV7eB14V, 5J4PBeAoDt679T2PJD1Ys1gyi2C1N65tFL71coYPUttPL9dpdt3, 5J3TbqXNZkzi2chux679A3KLLyZmWEmFUJmvR54FaL25qWJnM41,

#### Step 2: Figuring out the Private key

I'm a bit stumped here. The possible private keys don't match any of the addresses listed.

Comment: Nope, the private key isn't there :p.

Comment: incidentally, since one of the words is recursion, I went at least three deep, copying the output into the input on each of these words, plus the .txt files extensions for those that had them. Still got nothing

Comment: @Sconibulus That's a smart idea. I would bet that plays a role somewhere

Answer (score -1):

I added privkeys and the result was - i add privkeys and check real ones - the results was -

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4imW.jpg

Then I used script with number from this question URL number -

> 41664

the hash from the hint was the same so this was the answer.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the result in that imgur link - could you clarify?

Comment: Angel, you seem to have got the answer, but good answers need an explanation of the steps you took, could you please add some detail?